# Set default page template on Communication site with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, page-layout, communication-site

Is there a way to tick the "Set default selection" property of a page template, so that it will be use as the default page template?

[image]

I'm trying to find a way of doing this programmatically, preferably with PowerShell / PnP but so far I have found no clues on how this can be done.

Comment: Where is this "Set default selection" option in SharePoint UI? Can you add any screenshot to your question if possible?

Comment: @GaneshSanap updated post with screenshot of the UI. It is in the Create Page / News dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint is managing default page template using Web Property Bag with name `DefaultNewPageTemplateId` where it's storing `Unique Id` of `File` object of Site Page List Item.

[image]

You can set this property bag using any object model e.g. REST API, CSOM, PnP.PowerShell.

Below is the same for doing same using `PnP.PowerShell`

```
Connect-PnPOnline "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/testcommunity" -Interactive
$page = Get-PnPPage -Identity "Templates/Page-Template-2.aspx" #Relative Page Template Url
$pageFile = $page.GetPageFile()
$web = Get-PnPWeb
Add-PnPPropertyBagValue -Key "DefaultNewPageTemplateId" -Value $pageFile.UniqueId -Web $web
```

If you receive error like `(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) Site might have NoScript enabled, this prevents setting some property bag values`. In this case you need enable scripting which you can set using [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35588). Below are the commands for the same:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com
Set-SPSite -Identity "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/testcommunity" -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

**Note:** I couldn't find any official documentation for that but I am big fan of [SharePoint Client Browser](https://github.com/bramdejager/spcb) which helps me most of the time for this kind of scenario when I don't get anything from official Microsoft documentation :)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work well. Too bad we need to Enable scripting to make it work.