# Setting the default page template through Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, administration, sitepages

I'm creating a Power Automate flow with which among other things I would like to set the default page template in a newly created site.

I have the whole site creation part done, as well as retrieving the id of the template to use, but I can't figure out how to set the default page template.

I know it is done through the 'DefaultNewPageTemplateId' option, which I can see in the 'AllProperties' of a site, but how can I actually set it?

This is more or less a follow-up question to [Set default page template on Communication site with PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307239/set-default-page-template-on-communication-site-with-powershell/309776#309776)

Answer (score 1):

Previously I have done it using below SharePoint REST API endpoint and payload with JavaScript:

```
<button type="button" onclick="SetDefaultPageTemplate()"> Set Default Page Template</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SPConnect/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetDefaultPageTemplate() {
        var webEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web";

        //Visual template: ac3c4a88-04f2-4e54-a411-df9899c90df5
        var webProperties = {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Web' },
            'DefaultNewPageTemplateId': 'ac3c4a88-04f2-4e54-a411-df9899c90df5'
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: webEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": "*"
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(webProperties),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Try using REST API endpoint URL and payload like above in your Power automate flow and see if it works for you.

**Related Read**:

1. [Set a page template as default page template in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/05/26/set-a-page-template-as-default-page-template-in-sharepoint-online/)